# Is it possible to do interpolation search to find fixed point in an array?

Tags: arrays, interpolation, binary-search

In a sorted array **with no duplicate** values, can we use the interpolation search to find if there is a fixed point in an array such as array[i] ==i?

This is the code for the interpolation search :

```
public static int interpolationSearch(int[] array, int x) {
 if (array == null || array.length==0) {
        return;
 }

    int low = 0;
    int high = array.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while (array[low] != array[high] && x >= array[low] && x <= array[high]) {
        mid = low + ((x - array[low]) * (high - low) / (array[high] - array[low]));

        if (array[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (x < array[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    } 

    if (x == array[low])
        return low ;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

I find many times that we can use the binary search in an array to find a fixed point, it's done in O(log(n)). But since  the interpolation search is "just" an improved version of the binary search it's theortically possible to use it to find that point no? 
I tried naively to remove x in the code above and in the interpolation formula but it doesn't give always the correct result. I don't know if there is another relation for that or even if we can really do it with interpolation?

Comment: What language is this? What problems do you have with the code?

Comment: Yes, you can use interpolation search on sorted arrays of integers. Why wouldn't you be able to do so?

Comment: @Bergi, it's java. The problem in interpolation formula  is that we look for a value in a sorted array which we ALREADY know in advance (which I called "x" above). But, when we look if a fixed point exist, we don't look for a fixed value in advance, we don't have a value for that x. It's what got me confused. I don't know if it's clear for you now?

Comment: So you're asking how [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) works? Yes, we always do know the value `x` that we want to find, but we don't know *where* it is in the array (or whether at all). Therefore we use a binary-search-like algorithm, but instead of dividing each range in half, we take an educated guess for the "`mid`" that we look at.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of integers with no duplicates, yes, you can do this. The reason why is that if A is a sorted array of integers, then the new array B given by B[i] = A[i] - i is also sorted, so it's possible to apply interpolation sort to it.

This does not generally hold for arrays of non-integer values, though. For example, consider the array A = [0, 0.5, 3], which is sorted in ascending order. Then B = [0, -0.5, 1] is not sorted.

There is likely a bug somewhere in your code if this isn't working correctly.